# Is it possible to embed a manifest file inside the executable of a VB.NET (VS2010) project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, manifest, dpi

I'm currently working on a small VB.NET app on VS2010, and it seems that setting the "dpiAware" field on True in the project's manifest file is the only way of having the program not come up as a blurry mess on newer PCs.

The thing is, i really need (not allowed to explain why) to have this setting "packed" in the executable and not have it in a separate file that needs to come along with it.

After some research, it seems to be possible to embed the manifest file inside the exe file, but the instructions in my case are often unclear due to being written for newer versions of VS and/or different languages. Maybe it's even possible to change the dpiAware field in-code and not having to mess with external files, i'm not really sure.

Hopefully some of you had some experience in this department.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you check in the `Bin/Debug` or `Bin/Release` folders what has become of your `app.manifest` file? -- Are you referring to a Windows Forms Project? Tag your question accordingly (the Tag is `winforms`, in that case). -- The DpiAwareness setting can also be set in `App.config`. You didn't specify what .Net version you're targeting and what System versions you're supporting.

Comment: Project > Add New Item > pick "Application Manifest File".  Editing hints [are here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034).

Comment: You specify an manifest on the command line (and an icon). However if you need more than those two only then all 3+ need to be in a `.res` file. See `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\vbc /?`.